# C# - AdjustTokenPrivileges not working on 32bit

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, 32bit-64bit, privileges

I am trying to obtain a privilege in my .NET 4 C# application. This code works and the privilege is obtained successfully, but only on 64bit systems. When the same code is run on a 32bit system, the code fails at AdjustTokenPrivileges with this exception:

Invalid access to memory location. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)

I've tried modifying the code to fix the issue, but nothing has been working and I am pretty stumped.

Any ideas on why this fails on 32bit systems? It fails on both Windows Vista and 7 32bit, so it is a 32bit specific problem.

***Updated with correct code in 2022. The below code is now correct and can be used in your application.***

The method:

```
public static void EnableDisablePrivilege(string PrivilegeName, bool EnableDisable)
{
    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, PrivilegeName, out var luid)) throw new Exception($"EnableDisablePrivilege: LookupPrivilegeValue failed: {Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()).Message}");

    if (!OpenProcessToken(Process.GetCurrentProcess().SafeHandle, TokenAccessLevels.AdjustPrivileges, out var tokenHandle)) throw new Exception($"EnableDisablePrivilege: OpenProcessToken failed: {Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()).Message}");

    var tokenPrivileges = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES { PrivilegeCount = 1, Privileges = new[] { new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES { LUID = luid, Attributes = (uint)(EnableDisable ? 2 : 4) } } };
    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(tokenHandle, false, ref tokenPrivileges, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out _))
    {
        tokenHandle.Dispose();
        throw new Exception($"EnableDisablePrivilege: AdjustTokenPrivileges failed: {Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()).Message}");
    }
    else tokenHandle.Dispose();
}
```

Implementation:

```
EnableDisablePrivilege("SeManageVolumePrivilege", true);
```

PInvoke declarations:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LUID
{
    private uint lowPart;
    private int highPart;

    public uint LowPart { get => lowPart; set => lowPart = value; }

    public int HighPart { get => highPart; set => highPart = value; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
{
    private LUID luid;
    private uint attributes;

    public LUID LUID { get => luid; set => luid = value; }

    public uint Attributes { get => attributes; set => attributes = value; }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
{
    private uint privilegeCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    private LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] privileges;

    public uint PrivilegeCount { get => privilegeCount; set => privilegeCount = value; }

    public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges { get => privileges; set => privileges = value; }
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(SafeProcessHandle ProcessHandle, TokenAccessLevels DesiredAccess, out SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(SafeAccessTokenHandle TokenHandle, bool DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, uint BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, out uint ReturnLength);

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName, out LUID lpLuid);
```

Comment: Have you verified the structure is the correct size on the 32-bit systems?  What does the 256 stand for exactly?

Comment: "Specifies the size, in bytes, of the buffer pointed to by the PreviousState parameter. This parameter can be zero if the PreviousState parameter is NULL." That is not the problem though. If I set all of those optional parameters to null/0, the same problem still occurs.

Comment: Hi there is an err, that you may did not saw, but you use SafeArray with the parametr SizeConst which will result in compile error. You should use the `UnmanagedType.ByValArray` which is inplace array as it should be according to the C++ TOKEN_PRIVILEGES structure.

Comment: second think is that it's nice that you define getter and setter, but the unmanaged code will still access the private members since it will work with the memory directly. It will work as it is, but once you start adding some other logic to the getter / setter. It will be problem since it won't be used by the unmanaged code.

Comment: @PavelB. Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected this in my code a long time ago, but did not update it here. I have updated this post now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed, just had to put a ref before NewState:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, bool DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, uint Bufferlength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);
```